# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Java Error

Tags: java, niagara-ax

```
public void onStart() throws Exception
{
  // start up code here
}enter code here

public void onExecute() throws Exception
{
  // execute code (set executeOnChange flag on inputs)
  String tmp = getInASCIIString().getValue();
  setOutCSVString(new BStatusString(AsciiToBinary(tmp)));
}

public void onStop() throws Exception
{
  // shutdown code here
}

public static String AsciiToBinary(String asciiString) throws Exception
{  
  String padding = "00000000";
  StringBuffer dataString = new StringBuffer();
  StringBuffer outCSV = new StringBuffer();
  StringTokenizer Values = new StringTokenizer(asciiString,",");
     while (Values.hasMoreTokens()) 
     {
        String bin = padding + Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(Values.nextToken()));
        String reversedString = new StringBuffer(bin.substring(bin.length() - 8, bin.length())).reverse().toString();
        dataString.append(reversedString); 
     }
  try
  {
      char[] charArray = dataString.toString().toCharArray();
      for (int i = 1; i < charArray.length; i++) 
      {
        if (charArray[i] == '1')
        {
          outCSV.append(i+"");
          outCSV.append(',');
        } 
      } 
      if (outCSV.toString().length() > 1)  
      {
        return outCSV.toString().substring(0, outCSV.toString().length()-1);
      }
      else
      {
        return outCSV.toString();
      }
  }
  catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
  {
    return ""; 
  }

}
```

We use a Tridium- which uses Java as the backend. This program *seems* to be randomly and occasionally throwing an error. I'm only limited to the packages that are pre-installed, including: java.util, java.baja.sys, javax.baja.status, javax.baja.util, com.tridium.program

Which is why some of the code is written using the logic/functions that it does. Anyway- I cannot figure out *why* this is throwing an error. Any thoughts?

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 15 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

Full stack trace:

> ```
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 15
>  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>  at com.korsengineering.niagara.conversion.BStatusNumericToStatusBoolean.changed(BStatusNumericToStatusBoolean.java:38)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.fireComponentEvent(ComponentSlotMap.java:1000)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.modified(ComponentSlotMap.java:902)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.modified(ComplexSlotMap.java:1538)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.setDouble(ComplexSlotMap.java:1254)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.setDouble(BComplex.java:666)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.copyFrom(ComplexSlotMap.java:294)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.copyFrom(BComplex.java:246)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BLink.propagatePropertyToProperty(BLink.java:593)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BLink.propagate(BLink.java:523)
>  at com.tridium.sys.engine.SlotKnobs.propagate(SlotKnobs.java:56)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.modified(ComponentSlotMap.java:899)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.modified(ComplexSlotMap.java:1538)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.setDouble(ComplexSlotMap.java:1254)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.setDouble(BComplex.java:666)
>  at javax.baja.status.BStatusNumeric.setValue(BStatusNumeric.java:66)
>  at com.tridium.kitControl.conversion.BStatusStringToStatusNumeric.calculate(BStatusStringToStatusNumeric.java:161)
>  at com.tridium.kitControl.conversion.BStatusStringToStatusNumeric.changed(BStatusStringToStatusNumeric.java:155)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.fireComponentEvent(ComponentSlotMap.java:1000)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.modified(ComponentSlotMap.java:902)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.modified(ComplexSlotMap.java:1538)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.setString(ComplexSlotMap.java:1335)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.setString(BComplex.java:668)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.copyFrom(ComplexSlotMap.java:295)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.copyFrom(BComplex.java:246)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BLink.propagatePropertyToProperty(BLink.java:593)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BLink.propagate(BLink.java:523)
>  at com.tridium.sys.engine.SlotKnobs.propagate(SlotKnobs.java:56)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.modified(ComponentSlotMap.java:899)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.modified(ComplexSlotMap.java:1538)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.setString(ComplexSlotMap.java:1335)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.setString(BComplex.java:668)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComplexSlotMap.copyFrom(ComplexSlotMap.java:295)
>  at javax.baja.sys.BComplex.copyFrom(BComplex.java:238)
>  at javax.baja.control.BControlPoint.doExecute(BControlPoint.java:271)
>  at auto.javax_baja_control_BStringWritable.invoke(AutoGenerated)
>  at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.invoke(ComponentSlotMap.java:1599)
>  at com.tridium.sys.engine.EngineUtil.doInvoke(EngineUtil.java:49)
>  at com.tridium.sys.engine.EngineManager.checkAsyncActions(EngineManager.java:364)
>  at com.tridium.sys.engine.EngineManager.execute(EngineManager.java:209)
>  at com.tridium.sys.engine.EngineManager$EngineThread.run(EngineManager.java:691)
> ```

Comment: Exception is pretty well self descriptive. See your line 658.

Comment: @drgPP Except the exception doesn't contain any information about OP's code. The "line 658" is in java.lang.String. I doubt the error is actually there.

Comment: @Siguza seems so, my bad.This means OP has not evaluated his exception stacktrace correctly to point the real line that cause the problem.

Comment: @sinclair/drgPP/Siguza thanks for looking at the question. **SUPER** new to Java- kind of lost as to where to look to debug.

Comment: The method `AsciiToBinary` is not part of the stack trace, so how is it related to the question?

Comment: @Thomas Can you direct me to the actual function that _is_ faulting?

Comment: @SteveCarpenter No problem, we all started some day, but what you are doing in the catch-clause hurts my eyes ;-) Please add `e.printStackTrace()` before the `return ""` to get a qualified error message.

Comment: @SteveCarpenter I don't think you showed us the right code... error occurs in BStatusNumericToStatusBoolean.java  line 38. Could you post the code of this class?

Comment: Please include the stack trace **in the question**. I've done it for you this time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is happening outside your Program Object, once you wire your `outCSVString` to whatever other wire sheet logic you are linking it to. This is more than likely due to your `AsciiToBinary` method returning a null string output that the rest of your logic can't deal with.

Wire `outCSVString` to a `StringWritable` object that has a `StringCov` history extension on it, and look for what value the history records at the same timestamp where you see the exception, to make sure your ProgramObject is generating the output you expect.

Regarding your `AsciiToBinary` method, the Tridium framework is limited in the modules it provides and what you can import, however it does come packaged with Apache Oro Regular Expression Tools Version 2.0.8.  Search for "oro" in the Niagara Help file for more information.

In my experience, you will be more assured that `outCSVString` will always follow a desired format if you use a regular expression with a substitution to build the string, rather than tokenizing and iterating through the string yourself.